# Is the "grain" in this converted image indicative of Steganography?

Tags: encryption, steganography

I'm checking an image in every way I can for steganography. I've checked the file signature, compared it to it's original source and extracted the pixels, many methods but nothing's coming up. Apologies if I say something that isn't right because I'm very new to cryptography, especially steganography.

However something I was recommended from a hacking CTF guide was converting the file to .xmp to view the palette. So I used imagemagick in my terminal to do so. The result has some weird "grain" around areas of the image and I wanted to know if this was just due to the image conversion or if it may be bytes that have been tampered with and indicative of steganography.

Sorry if this is a dumb question because I figure it's likely due to the image conversion, but I just wanted to check.

[image]

Comment: You can try with some other images to see that that is normal or not. That is the way.

Comment: If you see a bunch of dark dots in an otherwise background of differing color and sharpness, then it's not the image conversion. Unless it is seriously broken of course, but I don't think that's the case here.